# Adding jars to java application using Interface name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, osgi, classloader

I am developing a media application where the user should be able to dynamically load tools from a central database at runtime. These will mostly need to be signal processing modules for manipulating audio and video. I have been reading about implementing a custom class loader, but it seems that one must know the names of the classes in order to use the classLoader. This doesn't seem right to me. I want to be able to build these modules after the application has been deployed (and possibly open up a public api for their creation).

I was thinking of requiring the modules to extend an abstract class that implements an interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractModule implements myInterface{
    //....
}
```

I still don't have any way of knowing what the authors of these Modules will name the subclass...

I have read a bit about osgi bundles, and that seems promising... However I obviously dont want to redesign my entire architecture... is it possible to have this part of my application use Osgi bundles? My feeling is no, since it seems that Osgi bundles require their own container to run in.

Anyway, what is the best, least hacky, and most stable way to let my applcation load modules dynamically. The modules need some sort of standardization (like extending an abstract class).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is such a beautiful use case for OSGI. So I guess the question is - is this a desktop application or server based? Note that it IS possible to use OSGI on the Desktop, but your container choices will be different if you go this route.

---

**EDIT**

For Desktop applications you would best be served by using [Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html) or [Eclipse Equinox](http://eclipse.org/equinox/). Both can be embedded very nicely into standalone, rich clients. For server applications I cannot recommend JBoss 7 highly enough. You get a fast Java EE 6 server with first class support for OSGI modules. I'm still unsure on the exact setup of your architecture, you mention both a (rich sounding) client and a Java EE server. Could you elaborate some more?

Comment: I have been reading this document, and like you said it sounds beautiful. Can you elaborate on how the container choices will be different? I am writing a muti-tierd java-ee app. Osgi will have to run in (or perhaps alongside?) an app-client running in an ACC deployed through glassfishes javaws service. After quickly skimming this article it seems that this will be as simple as instantiating a Felix object. Sorry, I need to learn more about how osgi works (in particular its interaction with its container environment) POSTING LINK IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html#ApacheFelixFrameworkLaunchingandEmbedding-embedding

Comment: I added some detail to my answer. If you could elaborate more on your client I could narrow down the choices even more.

Comment: I have a rich client processing audio and video. I want to load filters and other tools from a library of resources on the application server (glassfish3.x). I already have a mechanism in place in load data from the server (pictures, audio, video, etc). That was very straightforward. But when It came to provide functionality, loading classes using a classloader seemed like a nightmare. Do you think there would be any advantage of encapsulating resources that are purely data (byte[]) as an osgi bundle? So that ALL the resources (data, programmatic) would be in a consistent format?

Comment: You could always bundle resources as a **part** of an OSGI bundle. Though that probably would not be the most efficient use of one. The filters and tools should definitely be modules though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Top Notch answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't disagree with the other answers, of course.

In addition, one of your concerns seems to be about the necessity to have an OSGi container. This is true: Felix (APLv2), Equinox (EPL) and Knopflerfish (BSD) are examples of open source OSGi Framework implementations. However they are quite lightweight and embeddable, in fact you can embed them with around 5-10 lines of code. I wrote a [blog post](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html) on this subject a while ago that may help to get you started.

In other words, there is no necessity to convert your entire application to OSGi (though you may want to do that for other reasons, such as modularity and maintainability). You can create a small OSGi container within your application that is used purely for loading these pluggable tools.

Some other miscellaneous points:

- Holly mentioned using OSGi Services and I strongly agree. The tool bundles should publish services that your application listens for.
- Rather than a database for the tool bundles, I would recommend using a repository technology such as OBR. This will allow the dependencies between tools and libraries to be managed by a resolver, making it easier for developers to contribute tools into your platform. Note that the physical storage for an OBR repository can still be an RDBMS if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Perception - you should consider OSGi for this. No sense in reinventing the wheel. But if you have no other choice:

Create your standerdized interface that each module needs to implement, e.g.

```
public interface ModuleInterface {
    public String greet(String name);   
}
```

A module's implementation could look like this:

```
public class MyModule implements ModuleInterface {

    @Override
    public String greet(String name) {
        return "Hi "+name+"!";
    }

}
```

You can then package these classes in a jar (that is not sealed) to create a module. Your application (which includes the common ModuleInterface class) can then load the module by doing e.g.

```
URL classUrl = new URL("file:///modules/server/ModuleJar.jar");
URL[] classUrls = {classUrl};
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
Class<?> clazz = ucl.loadClass("com.example.MyModule");
ModuleInterface firstModule = (ModuleInterface)clazz.newInstance();
System.out.println(firstModule.greet("John Doe"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to scan the classpath and check class by class.
It is a very annoying thing to do.
Check [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/), it will help you get all subtypes of some type without too much work

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is a lovely use case for OSGi. One piece which hasn't been mentioned is OSGi services. Services are registered in a service registry, and are looked up by interface name. If there are multiple services which implement the same interface, you can get a list back which contains all of them.

You can register and access services programatically, but it's better to do it declaratively using declarative services or blueprint. Both provide simple dependency injection for OSGi services. Blueprint is based on spring dm and so should look pretty familiar if you're used to spring. If you're using Glassfish I believe it has a different system for injecting OSGi services, so you can use that or install a blueprint implementation into your container.

Many application servers, including Glassfish, JBoss, Geronimo, and WebSphere Application Server allow you to run applications in an OSGi container while still using Java EE patterns like servlets and JPA. (If you want to google more, Glassfish call this hybrid applications, which gives you the idea, and others call it Enterprise  OSGi.) This may allow you to move to a nice clean implementation of an OSGi solution without major rearchitecting.

--

Enterprise OSGi in Action: http://www.manning.com/cummins